# How do I filter an SCons Glob result?

Tags: scons

I sometimes want to exclude certain source files from a Glob result in SCons. Usually it's because I want to compile that source file with different options. Something like this:

```
objs = env.Object(Glob('*.cc'))
objs += env.Object('SpeciallyTreatedFile.cc', CXXFLAGS='-O0')
```

Of course, that creates a problem for SCons:

```
scons: *** Two environments with different actions were specified
       for the same target: SpeciallyTreatedFile.o
```

I usually work around this using the following idiom:

```
objs = env.Object([f for f in Glob('*.cc')
  if 'SpeciallyTreatedFile.cc' not in f.path])
```

But that's pretty ugly, and gets even uglier if there's more than one file to be filtered out.

Is there a clearer way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got fed up duplicating the `[f for f in Glob ...]` expression in several places, so I wrote the following helper method and added it to the build Environment:

```
import os.path

def filtered_glob(env, pattern, omit=[],
  ondisk=True, source=False, strings=False):
    return filter(
      lambda f: os.path.basename(f.path) not in omit,
      env.Glob(pattern))

env.AddMethod(filtered_glob, "FilteredGlob");
```

Now I can just write

```
objs = env.Object(env.FilteredGlob('*.cc',
  ['SpeciallyTreatedFile.cc', 'SomeFileToIgnore.cc']))
objs += env.Object('SpeciallyTreatedFile.cc', CXXFLAGS='-O0')
```

Using this pattern it would be easy to write something similar that uses, say, a regexp filter as the `omit` argument instead of a simple list of filenames, but this works well for my current needs.

Comment: I don't see any other good way. So, you are on right road. Just implement own Glob with exclude filter.

Comment: I'v need a variant of `Glob` that can handle regexps instead of glob patterns. I need to collect source files with different extension lengths: `.c`, `.f`, `.cpp`, `.adb`, etc and `Glob` cannot handle this in one pass. Should I use `os.listdir`, `filter`, `map`-`env.File` for this or do you have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but deserves an update since it still shows up on search.

SCons 2.3.5 Introduced the `exclude` keyword argument to `Glob`, such that the following is valid now:

```
objs = env.Object(Glob('*.cc'), exclude=['SpeciallyTreatedFile.cc'])
objs += env.Object('SpeciallyTreatedFile.cc', CXXFLAGS='-O0')
```

Since `exclude` takes a list, many excludes can be included, and the exclude list itself may contain the same kind of wildcards as the glob.  The user documentation lists the following example:

```
sources = Glob('*.cpp', exclude=['os_*_specific_*.cpp']) + Glob('os_%s_specific_*.cpp'%currentOS)
```