# Exclude deprecated files from build using SCons

Tags: scons, nightly-build

How can I tell Scons to exclude some files from build sources.

I have all files in folder called src. Following is my code snippet which include files for build.

```
env = Environment()
env.Program(target='project’,  source=[Glob(’src/*.cpp’)]   )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related/duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518715/how-do-i-filter-an-scons-glob-result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the existing documentation, [the MAN page](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html) as well as [the UserGuide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html), you'll find that the `Glob()` command supports the `exclude` parameter. You can use it to specify a list of patterns that should get excluded from the returned list.

Another option is to simply filter the list of found entries yourself, remember that you have the full power of Python at your fingertips:

```
excluded_files = ['src/a.cpp', 'src/b.cpp']
sources = [x for x in Glob('src/*.cpp') if str(x) not in excluded_files]
env.Program('project', sources)
```

Comment: Actually Glob now has an exclude parameter.  So you could skip the list comprehension.